# How to access Class properties outside of JavaScript Classes

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

How is the sound property not properly private in this JavaScript class? Additionally, how can it be accessed outside the class? I saw this in a video and attempted to access the sound property outside the class and could not.

```
class Dog {
  constructor() {
    this.sound = 'woof';
  }
  talk() {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

It's not private because you can access it from the outside after creating an instance of the class.

```js
class Dog {
  constructor() {
    this.sound = 'woof';
  }
  talk() {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
}

let dog = new Dog();
console.log(dog.sound); // <--

// To further drive the point home, check out
// what happens when we change it
dog.sound = 'Meow?';
dog.talk();
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you.

Comment: @Steez Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the class using `new`. When you don't have an instance of the class, the constructor has yet to be executed, so there's no sound property yet.

```
var foo = new Dog();
console.log(foo.sound);
```

or

This will assign a default property to the Dog class without having to create a new instance of it.

```
Dog.__proto__.sound = 'woof';
console.log(Dog.sound);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create instance of your class.

```js
class Dog {
  constructor() {
    this.sound = 'woof';
  }
  talk() {
    console.log(this.sound);
  }
}

console.log(new Dog().sound);
```