# How can I access a variable declared in the constructor from a method?

Tags: javascript, class

```
class X {
   constructor (e) {
        let someVar = e; 
   }
   SomeMethod () {
        console.log(this.someVar);   
   }
}
```

It gave me undefined, so how can I get the value of "someVar" ?;

Comment: You can't; it's not a class property, it's a locally-scoped variable.

Comment: Have a look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955538/what-happens-with-var-variables-inside-a-javascript-constructor

Comment: Same way as in Python--except `this` instead of `self`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access Class properties outside of JavaScript Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241079/how-to-access-class-properties-outside-of-javascript-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor, instead of `let` use `this`:

```
constructor (e) {
    this.someVar = e; 
}
```

I strongly advise learning more about variable scope in javascript. You can consult [this post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-variables-scope-hoisting-in-javascript).

Also, if you want to know more about `class` in javascript, consult [this nice post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-classes-in-javascript).

Follows a full working example:

```js
class X {
   constructor (e) {
        this.someVar = e; 
   }
   SomeMethod () {
        console.log(this.someVar);   
   }
}

const obj = new X("Some text");
obj.SomeMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class X {
   constructor (e) {
        this.someVar = e; 
   }
   SomeMethod () {
        console.log(this.someVar);   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, an object field can be declared with the `this` keyword in the `constructor` function. Therefore, your `someVar` is just a local variable **within** the scope of the constructor.

You need to do this:

```
class X {
   constructor (e) {
        this.someVar = e; //Now, someVar is a proper field of any object instance of X
   }
   SomeMethod () {
        console.log(this.someVar);   
   }
}
```